# How to get text form data by PHP using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to get text form data by PHP using ajax.
PHP works but I could not give a user input datum to PHP.
How can I give it to PHP?

HTML

```
<form id="form_test">
    <input name="message" type="text" value="123.456.789" size="12">
    <button type="button" onclick="exec_php()">Send</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function exec_php() {
    var formdata = new FormData($('#form_test').get(0));

    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: formdata,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "text"
    })
        .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert("data: " + data);
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("fail");  
        });
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
echo basename($_GET['message']);
```

The formdata in Javascript is empty.
So I think the way of getting text form data in javascript is wrong.
Could you tell me the correct way?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you getting an error in the browser console?

Comment: You're attempting to do a `GET` request when sending the form data. You are sending **data**, so you need to do a `POST` request: `type: "POST"` and `$_POST['message']`.

Comment: lol was gona say the same

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! I could get data after I changed into POST.